# Don't know what this popup is called

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make a popup like this. The image will pop up when the user click on its above button.
[image]

Actually, i don't really know what it is called so that i can't find links to help me to do this.

So any links or help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your level with javascript/html/css ?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? You can create something like this by styling a `<div>` with `display:none`and toggling it's state by clicking on your button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EjCc6/). It's just written from scratch.

All you need is a button (visible) and the "popup" (hidden). Now, you add an event listener to check if button is clicked and fade in/out the "popup".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#columns').on('click', function() {
    $('#selector').fadeToggle(750);
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/h7pxU/

You can do the same by simply toggling/show hide div

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $('.popup').toggle();
});
```

The .popup needs to be with `position: absolute` and its parent must have `position: relative`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do not only post a link, include your code and explain what you do please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use qTip here, http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/
it's nice and easy to use. You can create a qtip with html code

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic demo, it uses plain JavaScript without any libraries. Please notice that `document.querySelector` and `addEventListener` aren't implemented in IE prior version 9, so you may want to use jQuery or another JS-Framework.

#### HTML

First of all, you need the correct structure. You'll need a wrapper, the button, and the menu:

```
<div class="menuwrapper">
    <button>Click me!</button>
    <div class="menu">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Auto-save this page</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Make this page private</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Hide notifications</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

Now we need to style those elements

```
.menuwrapper{
    overflow:none;
    position:relative; // this will have an effect on the absolute position later on
}
.menuwrapper > button{
   border: 1px solid;  // style the way you want it
}

.menuwrapper > div{
   border: 1px solid;  // again, style the way you want it
   display:none;       // hide the div
   position: absolute; // use absolute positioning
   top:110%;           // place it about 10% of the containing container's height below it
   z-index:2;          // place it above other elements
}


.menuwrapper> div > label{
   display:block;      // again, customize this.
}
```

#### JavaScript

Now you need to add an event listener to all the wrappers.

```
var results = document.querySelectorAll(".menuwrapper"); // save all menues
var i; // index
for(i = 0; i < results.length; ++i){
    // for every menuwrapper, add an listener
    results[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        // make the contained menu visible
        this.querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'block';

        // stop the event from propagation
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}

// Almost the same, but if anything outside of the
// menuwrapper is clicked then all menus should be closed.
window.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var i;
    var results = document.querySelectorAll(".menuwrapper .menu");
    for(i = 0; i < results.length;  ++i)
        results[i].style.display = 'none';        
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cwhuj/)

See also:

- MDN: [`element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.querySelector)